# How to replace all section signs § using javascript (node js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, string, replace

I have a string which contains the section sign `§`. I need to replace it with a `&` symbol
I have tried `.replace(/§/g, '&');` and `.replace(/\u2002/g, '&');` but it does nothing. How do I replace the section sign with something else?

**EDIT**: this is a node js application

Comment: Remember that `.replace()` doesn't mutate the string that it's being called on, it instead produces a new string with the replaced items, so you need to store the return value of `.replace()`

Comment: @Nick Parsons I do understand this

Comment: There are a few tools to inspect strings. E.g., when doing `"a § b".length`, I expect `5`. When doing `Array.from("a § b")`, I expect `[ "a", " ", "§", " ", "b" ]`. When doing `Array.from("a § b", (string) => string.codePointAt())`, I expect `[ 97, 32, 167, 32, 98 ]`. When doing `Array.from("a § b", (string) => string.codePointAt().toString(16).toUpperCase().padStart(2, "0")).join(" ")`, I expect `"61 20 A7 20 62"`. With these assumptions, [the answer by blex](/a/67664916/4642212) (or `.replaceAll("§", "&")`) is absolutely correct. [Edit] your post and provide a [mre] we can work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```js
const str = "Tom § Jerry are a cat § a mouse";
console.log( str.replace(/§/g, '&') );
```

Comment: This does not work with my nodejs script, it stays unreplaced

Comment: Could you edit your question to add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which any of us can just copy § paste in a file and run, and reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 0):

Map the str and replace § with & using its index position;

```js
const str = "Tom § Jerry are a cat § a mouse";

const arr = str.split(" ")
arr.map((val, index) => {
if (val === "§"){
arr[index] = `&`;
} 

})
console.log(arr.join(" "))
```